# PHP Symfony authentication/authorization with Sign in with {Google/Facebook/etc}

Tags: php, symfony, authentication

So I am planning to offer authentication using Google and will not have any credentials or account specific information on my side other than a user id and a role. Does anyone know how to go about making a user appear authenticated to symfony with just the id? I've seen custom user providers but they require password, salt, hashing algorithms and what not which I don't have/need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For implementing Google/Facebook sign in, HWIOAuth Bundle is a great choice. It supports more than 20 service providers. The entire process of implementing the Facebook and Google authentication is bit too long to be posted here. 
You may read a step by step instruction here: http://praveesh4u.github.io/blog/2014/01/23/oauth-in-symfony/

Comment: Thanks, OAuthUser and OAuthUserProvider has the code I'm looking for. I actually took a look at the HWIOAuth bundle before, but had drop it due to lack of documentation and didn't feel like going through all the code. Didn't take long to get OAuth for Google up and running, just needed to figure out how to integrate with symphony with only an id.

Answer (score 0):

I use next code for this:

```
/**
 * Sign in with Facebook
 * @return redirect
 */
public function signInAction() {
    $request = $this->get('request');
    $session = $this->get('session');
    // Facebook init
    $facebook = $this->get('bw.user.social')->getFacebook();

    if ($request->query->has('code')) {
        if ($facebook->getUser()) {
            $userProfile = $facebook->api('/me/');
            if ($userProfile) {
                $user = $this->getDoctrine()
                        ->getRepository('BWUserBundle:User')
                        ->loadUserBySocialId('facebookId', $userProfile['id']);
                if ($user == NULL) {
                    // Email existence check
                    $isEmailExists = $this->getDoctrine()
                            ->getRepository('BWUserBundle:User')
                            ->isEmailExists($userProfile['email']);
                    if ($isEmailExists) {
                        $session->getFlashBag()->add('danger', '<b>Error!</b> e-mail "'. $userProfile['email'] .'" already exists.');
                        return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('home'));
                    }

                    $i = 0;
                    do {
                        $username = $userProfile['username'] . ($i ? '_'. $i : '');
                        $isUsernameExists = $this->getDoctrine()
                                ->getRepository('BWUserBundle:User')
                                ->isUsernameExists($username);
                        $i++;
                    } while ($isUsernameExists);
                    // Создание нового пользователя
                    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
                    $role = $em->getRepository('BWUserBundle:Role')->findOneBy(array(
                        'role' => 'ROLE_USER',
                    ));
                    $user = new User();
                    $user
                            ->setFacebookId($userProfile['id'])
                            ->setEmail($userProfile['email'])
                            ->setUsername($username)
                            ->setActive(TRUE)
                            ->setConfirm(TRUE)
                            ->setHash('')
                            ->addRole($role)
                            ->generatePassword()
                        ;
                    $em->persist($user);
                    $em->flush();
                }
                if ($user) {

                    $this->authorizeUser($user); // return TRUE if success
                }
            }
        }
    } else {
        $params = array(
            'scope' => $this->get('service_container')->getParameter('social')['facebook']['scopes'],
            'redirect_uri' => $this->get('router')->generate('user_facebook_sign_in', array(), TRUE),
        );

        return $this->redirect($facebook->getLoginUrl($params));
    }

    return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('home'));
}

/** 
 * User auth
 * @param \BW\UserBundle\Entity\User $user
 * @return boolean
 */
protected function authorizeUser(User $user) {
    $request = $this->getRequest();

    /* Social User auth in Symfony */
    $token = new UsernamePasswordToken($user, $user->getPassword(), 'auth', $user->getRoles());
    $this->get('security.context')->setToken($token);

    // Fire the login event
    // Logging the user in above the way we do it doesn't do this automatically
    $event = new InteractiveLoginEvent($request, $token);
    $this->get('event_dispatcher')->dispatch('security.interactive_login', $event);

    return TRUE;
}
```

And also use [facebook PHP SDK](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-php-sdk)